# C++ memory deallocation, is it needed in this case?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to make bills, and their numbers(identifiers). Their numbers are automatically generated and are 9 characters long.

Here's my code <sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int counter = 1234;
char * BillNumber()
{
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        counter++;
        return "000000001";
    }

    int n = 0, c = counter;

    while (c != 0)
    {
        n++;
        c /= 10;
    }

    char * nrBill = new char[n + 1];
    _itoa_s(counter, nrBill, n + 1, 10);
    nrBill[n + 1] = '\0';

    int difference = 9 - n;
    if (difference == 0)
        return nrBill;

    char * helper = new char[difference + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < difference + 1; i++)
    {
        helper[i] = '0';
        if (i == difference)
            helper[i] = '\0';
    }

    strcat_s(helper, 10, nrBill);
    counter++;
    return helper;
}

int main()
{
    char * bill[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        bill[i] = BillNumber();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << bill[i] << endl;
    }

    //Deallocation
    /*for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        delete[] bill[i];
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to deallocate the memory like in the comment, I get an error. I understand why I get it, I mean I haven't even allocated my memory in the `main` function. So I actually need to deallocate it in the function `BillNumber`. But I don't think that is needed in the function either.

So my question is:

*Is memory deallocation actually needed here?*

<sup>1</sup>: I know that I am not using c++ coding standards, so please don't complain about that.*

Comment: Your code is full of bugs. And this isn't a debugging service, despite appearances.

Comment: Why do you think memory deallocation is not needed? Any time you allocate memory with `new`, you must deallocate it with `delete`. The rule is quite simple. You can make it even simpler by using RAII and standard C++ idioms, but you seem to have some reason to avoid those.

Comment: @CodyGray well, I am aware now that I need to deallocate the `nrBill` in my function `BillNumber()` , but how can I deallocate `helper` ? I mean I can't do something like: `delete[] helper; return helper;`

Comment: @Kapobajza You return pointer to helper and store it in bill so you only need to deallocate it in bill.

Comment: Right, you cannot do that. That is why C++ programmers use objects to encapsulate data, so that they don't have to do manual memory management. If you want to do it the C way, then you return a pointer from `BillNumber()`, which transfers the ownership of `helper` from the called function (`BillNumber`) to the calling function (`main`). The calling function `main` now has the responsibility to `delete[] helper` when it is done using it.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for your help, that's the answer I needed. I am really limited in this example, because it's an exercise from a test.

Comment: Don't allocate two different chunks of memory and return only one of them. Try to work out all your ifs and buts first then allocate one block of memory to fulfill whatever you need and return that.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean I haven't even allocated my memory in the main function. So I actually need to deallocate it in the function BillNumber. But I don't think that is needed in the function either.

Where the allocation happened doesn't matter, the point is if you allocated something, you need to deallocate it. For your code, because you're still using the pointers after `BillNumber()` called in `main()`, you have to deallocate them later in `main()`.

> When I try to deallocate the memory like in the comment, I get an error.

You need to debug the program to find out the real problems, here's one of the possibility:

```
char * nrBill = new char[n + 1];
_itoa_s(counter, nrBill, n + 1, 10);
nrBill[n + 1] = '\0';
```

`nrBill[n + 1]` is getting out of the bound of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing this `char * nrBill = new char[n + 1];` and this `char * helper = new char[difference + 1];` you are actually allocating memory on heap, which does not free up, unless you are calling it explicitely. you should call:

```
delete []nrBill; 
delete []helper[];
```

before returning from the function, or else you will get a memory leak. The objects nrBill and helper will never be freed-up, until the end of the program, which is not a problem in your case, because it will end soon, and the memory is restored, but if you develop an application which produces memory leaks and is working for long periods of time, then it will be a real problem.

Comment: I am aware that I need to `delete[] nrBill` , but if I do `delete[] helper` how will I return it then? I can't return an empty char pointer.

Comment: delete[]helper should be called in your main function, sorry! And with the name you give it there, like delete[] bill.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not deallocate `nrBill` when you return `helper`. That is a memory leak and a problem.

As for your question the memory deallocation is needed because you have manually allocated memory. However in your case there will not be any memory leak (aside the one I mentioned above) because the program finishes (main returns) and all allocated memory is freed anyway.